# Facebook login breaks when Facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm building an Android app that allows the user to log in with his facebook account. I followed the official tutorial and got it working perfectly.
That is untill I installed the facebook app on my phone.
When I try to log in and I press "log in with facebook" button I get a screen switch for half a second and then I get back to my login screen where I was before.

If I uninstall the app everythings works again. I believe the app is interfearing but I don't know how to handle it, I have found no one with my same problem.

I follow the official tutorial step by step, I have a main activity with a fragment containing a button.
Usually if you click the button the facebook login screen pops up and you're able to enter your credential.

Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you add you application package and hash to Android facebook app on developers.facebook.com ?
If you login using SDK UI, not installed Facebook app - key does not checked.

Comment: Yeah the key was not there. It was not my fault tho, but everything is now ok. thanks